# Change directory ownership in linux

Tags: linux, directory

The uploads directory is not writeable by a browser because of ownership.

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 masud masud   28 Mar 23 15:46 index.php


drwxrwxr-x  4 masud masud 4096 Mar 23 15:46 languages


drwxrwxr-x 11 masud masud 4096 Mar 23 16:16 plugins


drwxrwxr-x  3 masud masud 4096 Mar 23 16:11 themes


drwxrwxr-x  4 masud masud 4096 Mar  7 13:14 uploads
```

I want to change the ownership of the uploads directory.

Answer (score 0):

it will change the ownership of that directory
sudo chmod -R 0777 directory_name